# Find all possible pairs of $(m,n)$ such that $m^2+2m-35=2^n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Find all possible pairs of $(m,n)$ such that
> $$m^2+2m-35=2^n$$

This question was apparantly from Stanford sheets and I want to know some innovative and generalized ways to solve this question.

**Here is my approach**

First note that we can factor the quadratic as $$(m+7)(m-5)=2^n$$
Now we see that $(m+7)$ and $(m-5)$ are $12$ apart. And by some guessing we note that the only powers of two that are $12$ apart are $16$ and $4$.

Therefore we set, $$m+7=16 \:\:\textrm{or} \:\:m+7=-4$$
$$m=9\:\:\textrm{or}\:\:m=-11$$
And we get, the pairs $$(9,6)\:\:\textrm{and}\:\:(-11,6)$$
**This was also the official solution.**

But you see that here we didn't make a generalization. So can we make it in this case$?$ Like we did some guessing thing. Also I would appreciate other approaches.

Comment: can you please share a link to the source of this question...

Comment: Maybe by solving $m^2 + 2m -35 - 2^n$ you get $m = -1 - \sqrt{36+2^n} \hspace{0.2cm} \text{or} \hspace{0.1cm} -1 + \sqrt{36+2^n}$. Then it remaisn to find all $n$ such that   $\sqrt{36+2^n} \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2^a - 2^b = 12 ~: ~a,b \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}, ~a > b, ~c = (a - b) \implies $$

$$(2^b)(2^c - 1) = 12.$$

$(2^c - 1)~$  must be an odd number, and $2^b$ must be an element of $\{1,2,4\}.$

Further, $2^b \in \{1,2\} \implies (2^c - 1)~$ would have to be even.

This makes it **game over**.

Answer (score 1):

**Note that the following only works for restricted domain (will be explained through the method).

$$(m + 7)(m - 5) = 2^n \to (m + 1)(m + 1) - 36 = 2^n \to$$
$$(m + 1)^2 = (2^{\frac{n}{2}})^2 + 6^2$$

We have arrived at a form $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$. Hence, the solutions follow idea of pythagorean triples. To confirm this is true, your stated solution of $(9, 6)$ is satisfied by the triple $\{6, 8, 10\}, m+1 = 10 \text{ and } 2^\frac{n}{2} = 8$

We can generate triples accord. to the general form,

$$c = x^2 + y^2, b = 2xy, a = x^2 - y^2, \mathbf{x > y}$$

See that we already have $1$ of the triples, that is $6$. We can **either** set $a$ or $b$ = 6, to find our solutions (the question did not state the domain of solutions, so assume in $\mathbb{R}$).

When $\mathbf{b = 6}$, we obtain infinite solutions but satisfying, $y = \frac{3}{x}$. Similarly

Another way to think about this is that we have obtained parametric equations for $m,n$:

$$\to \big\{m, n: \begin{cases} m = x^2 + \frac{9}{x^2} - 1 \\ 2^\frac{n}{2} = x^2 - \frac{9}{x^2} \end{cases}, |x| > \sqrt{3} \big\}$$

When $\mathbf{a = 6}$, we obtain infinite solutions but satisfying, $y = \sqrt{x^2 - 6}$.

$$\to \big\{m, n: \begin{cases} m = 2x^2 - 7 \\ 2^\frac{n}{2} = 2x\sqrt{x^2 - 6} \end{cases}, x > \sqrt{6} \big\}$$

**The domains are restricted to the fact that $2^{\frac{n}{2}} > 0$, hence eliminating negative solutions.